# Drag, throw with ease in ActionScript 2.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, drag, throw

I'm developer of game called "throw" (Game available only as beta for beta testers).
Game is created using ActionScript 2.0 in Flash 8.

My question is, if someone could help me with throwing code.
What do I mean? I mean that if you drag movieclip called "Ball" it just follows your mouse until you drop it.

Pretty simple code:

```
on(press) {
    if (_root.ThrowZone.hitTest(this)) {
        startDrag(this);
    }
}

on(release) {
    if (_root.ThrowZone.hitTest(this)) {
        stopDrag();
    }
}
```

I also have simple gravity code set up, but I rather not to show it, since it is not "that" needed.
I want it to throw the "Ball" as you release movieclip, I mean that it will go straight up with different
speed depending on how fast you moved it before you released it, I also want it to get slow in and slow out as it gets up.
I have tried covering my Gravity code a bit, changing it and reversing it, reversing psychics but then it will
go up same way no wonder how you throw it.

If you really need to test the game in order to see how it works, tell me in comment, and I will put link to it in thread.

Comment: Instead of using AS2, why don't you use AS3? AS3 is more suitable for game development than AS2

Comment: Since I don't have AS2 testing environment right now, I can only suggest that you should instead of dragging the throwing object, drag the transparent target object, and make the throwing object travel towards the target object on every enterframe. Once click is released, use the remaining distance between them to calculate final velocity.

Answer (score 0):

I would go like this.
On your stage (root):

```
_global.$stage = this;
var isDragging = false;
var dragTarget = null;
$stage.onEnterFrame = function() {      
    if(isDragging){
         $stage.dragTarget._x = $stage._xmouse;
         $stage.dragTarget._y = $stage._ymouse;
    }       
}
```

Then on the Ball:

```
on(press) {
   $stage.isDragging = true;
   $stage.dragTarget = this;
}

on(release) {
   $stage.isDragging = false;
}
```